# How to calculate age based on Day/Month/Year values provided in a previous request? - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Values for day/month/year will be passed in request no.1 like `bday=${__Random(1,30, bda)}, bmonth=${__Random(1,12, bmont)} & byear=${__Random(1950,2000, byea)}.` I am storing the random values in the 3rd parameter and using it for further requests. Now, I need to calculate the Age in request no.2 and pass the value for 'Age' parameter. DOB format will be `D/MM/YY` and `DD/MM/YY` only when the date value is more than 9. Can anyone suggest on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate differences between 2 dates using i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), example syntax would be something like:

```
${__groovy((groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(new Date()\, Date.parse('dd-MM-yyyy'\,String.format('%02d'\, vars.get('bda') as int) + '-' + String.format('%02d'\, vars.get('bmont') as int) + '-' + vars.get('byea'))).days / 365).setScale(0\, java.math.RoundingMode.DOWN),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Date Delta with Groovy]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 1):

As you are storing Day Month Year in bda, bmont, byea.. you can use those variables in bean shell to calculate the age

1. First add a [beanshell post processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) to your request no 1 where you are generating random DOB.
2. in the post processor add the following code

   String year=vars.get("byea");

   String Month=vars.get("bmont");

   String Day = vars.get("bda");

   String birthDate=year+"-"+Month+"-"+Day;

   vars.put("birthDate",birthDate);

[image]

3. Add a [beanshell preprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to the request 2 where you want to pass age  and add the following code

   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
   String birthDate = vars.get("birthDate");

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

   Date dateOfBirth = sdf.parse(birthDate);

   Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();

   dob.setTime(dateOfBirth);

   Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

   int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

   if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) < dob.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {

   age--;

   } else if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dob.get(Calendar.MONTH)

   && today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {

   age--;

   }
   vars.put("age",String.valueOf(age));

as shown below
[image]

use `${age}`  and pass along pass in http request ..

For more information on Beanshell please [follow this link...](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

Please let me know if it helps..

Comment: Thanks for the great effort Rohit. It works perfectly.

Comment: if it helped you can accept the answer,see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers